# Draw PolyLine on map from json

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I would like to be able to display a Polyline on my map.
How can I get the index value from the JSON feed and put it's split values on-to it so that it can be used on Google Maps?

The polyline Lat/Lng is supplied via a JSON feed & split into array.

Like this:

> {"Id":13115604,"Rcvr":1,"HasSig":false,"Icao":"C820D4","Bad":false,"Reg":"ZK-NZG","FSeen":"/Date(1521839348845)/","TSecs":560,"CMsgs":4003,"Alt":17850,"GAlt":17838,"InHg":29.9080849,"AltT":0,"TAlt":34016,"Call":"ANZ99","Lat":-36.35348,"Long":174.387856,"PosTime":1521839878181,"Mlat":false,"Tisb":false,"Spd":426.4,"Trak":323.1,"TrkH":false,"TTrk":302.34375,"Type":"B789","Mdl":"Boeing
>   787 9","Man":"Boeing","CNum":"37963","From":"NZAA Auckland, New
>   Zealand","To":"RJAA Narita, Tokyo, Japan","Op":"Air New
>   Zealand","OpIcao":"ANZ","Sqk":"0222","Help":false,"Vsi":1792,"VsiT":0,"WTC":3,"Species":1,"Engines":"2","EngType":3,"EngMount":0,"Mil":false,"Cou":"New
>   Zealand","HasPic":false,"Interested":false,"FlightsCount":0,"Gnd":false,"SpdTyp":0,"CallSus":false,"ResetTrail":true,"Trt":5,"Year":"2014","Cot":[-36.993294,174.851651,70.0,-36.946243,174.894922,70.0,-36.934499,174.884431,325.0,-36.35348,174.387856,325.0]},

And this is the lat/lng values of the poly line:

> [-36.993294,174.851651,70.0,-36.946243,174.894922,70.0,-36.934499,174.884431,325.0,-36.35348,174.387856,325.0]

This is the index of values within the array that's received:

> [0]   Latitude of earliest coordinate [1] Longitude of earliest
>   coordinate [2]    Time of earliest coordinate ... [n-3]   Latitude of
>   latest coordinate [n-2]   Longitude of latest coordinate [n-1]    Time of
>   latest coordinate

This is what I have tried but I keep getting a "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error.

```
 var poly;
        var polyOptions = {
          strokeColor: '#ff0000',    
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,   
          strokeWeight: 3    
        }
        poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
        poly.setMap(Map);   

        for(var i=0; i<plane.Cot.length; i++){
            var loc = plane.Cot[i].split(',');
            var path = poly.getPath();    
            path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(loc[0], loc[1]));    
        }
```

Comment: What does "onclick" (in the title) have to do with your question? Your first question should be why doesn't it display at all. If you are using a JSON object, the `split(",") doesn't do anything useful.  What line do you get the error on?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a full working [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com) to test out what your path is receiving from the push. But go ahead and try this line of code that splits at the `,` and makes two arrays out of the split which is what I believe you are missing since it is trying to insert a value for an array that does not exist, hence the "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". Unless your `plane.Cot.length` is being used out of scope, this is the only error I can address without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, not that it completely matters, but some JS code testers will give you an error if you are calling the path BEFORE splitting your location into two arrays. That is of course if you setup a placeholder array for path that way you can store your `path` when you invoke `poly.getPath()` at the end of this function... Just a heads up for future reference.

Try this:

```
 var poly;
 var path = [];

        var polyOptions = {
          strokeColor: '#ff0000',    
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,   
          strokeWeight: 3    
        }
        poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
        poly.setMap(Map);   

        for(var i=0; i<plane.Cot.length; i++){
            var loc = plane.Cot[i].split(',', 2);  
            path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(loc[0], loc[1])); 
            poly.getPath();      
        }
```

Comment: Thanks I have added it to my code here: http://radar5.cf/fi, I will work on adding a JSBIN now although I have never been able to get them to work.

Comment: try this, @kdawg.. let me know how it works! Don't forget to provide a JSBIN or something of the sort like CodePen, or StackBlitz so that others may benefit from this and understand the context of this function and its scope. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Omar here is the json incase needed for others: radar1.ddns.net:8080/VirtualRadar/AircraftList.json?trFmt=f and the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/taht05pu/4/

Comment: `str.split([separator[, limit]])` based on this .. we should change the code to `var loc = plane.Cot[i].split([,[,2]]); `

Comment: Thanks for trying @Omar but it returns a plane.Cot[i].split is not a function error I will have a play and see what I can do.

Comment: @Oram I have got it working sort of, I have got it to show when I click on it but only shows the first little dot as seen here: https://ibb.co/fhEQ9n

Comment: Code:       
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(p.Cot[0], p.Cot[1])
    poly.push(coords);
    console.log(poly);

  var Itinerary = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: poly,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#ffd500',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 5
  });

        
Itinerary.setMap(Map);

Comment: http://www.virtualradarserver.co.uk/Documentation/Formats/AircraftList.aspx#note2